# 'Member' object has no attribute 'hasPermission'

Tags: discord

i wanted to make a bot to discord for delete messages easly. it works 3 months ago but now i got an error "  'Member' object has no attribute 'hasPermission' ". thanks for everyone to share opinion. have a nice day.

```
import discord
from discord.ext    import commands
from discord.ext.commands   import Bot
import asyncio


bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = 'botcuk')

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Streaming(name="admin biseyler deniyor", url='https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fw7L7ZO4z_A'))

 if message.content.startswith('botcuksil'):
        if (message.author.hasPermission('MANAGE_MESSAGES')):
            args = message.content.split(' ')
            if len(args) == 2:
                if args[1].isdigit():
                    count = int(args[1]) + 1
                    deleted = await message.channel.purge(limit = count)
                    await message.channel.send('{} mesaj silindi'.format(len(deleted)-1))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is throwing `'Member' object has no attribute 'hasPermission'` this error because 'Member' does not have an attribute named 'hasPermission'. To fix your problem, I have re-written your code and also given some explanation below the code:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext             import commands
from discord.ext.commands    import Bot
import asyncio

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = 'botcuk')

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Streaming(name="admin biseyler deniyor", url='https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fw7L7ZO4z_A'))

@client.event # we need to add and check for a client event
async def on_message(): # we need to execute the command when we recieve an message so we define a function called 'async def on_message():'
    if message.content.startswith('botcuksil'):
        if message.author.guild_permissions.manage_messages: # we need 'author.guild_permissions.(permission)' intead of 'if (message.author.hasPermission('MANAGE_MESSAGES'))'
            args = message.content.split(' ')
            if len(args) == 2:
                if args[1].isdigit():
                    count = int(args[1]) + 1
                    deleted = await message.channel.purge(limit = count)
                    await message.channel.send('{} mesaj silindi'.format(len(deleted)-1))
```

I have not tested this yet, but according to me, your problem: `'Member' object has no attribute 'hasPermission'` should be solved.

What you have done was `message.author.hasPermission('MANAGE_MESSAGES')` but message.author has no attribute like `hasPermission`.

---

### Summary of what I have done:

I have added a client event (`@client.event`) and an async function `on_message()`.

What it does is it checks if it is getting an message or not. If it detects a new message in any of the servers it is invited to, it triggers the code in `on_message()`.

As I said: What you have done was `message.author.hasPermission('MANAGE_MESSAGES')` but `message.author` has no attribute like `hasPermission`.

Instead of writing that, we can use `message.author.guild_permissions.manage_messages`. It checks if the message author's server's permissions include "manage_messages". Hope my solution fixes your problem.

Always happy to help!
-sqd mountains

Comment: hi, now it says " TypeError: on_message() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given " i tried to delete 1 and 1000 messages. also there is "  NameError: name 'client' is not defined " says. i solve this to change client to bot.event. by the way thank you so much for your help. i didn't expect that much help :).

Comment: i solved this also i changed async def on_message() to async def on_message(message):

Comment: i am always happy to help :)